# WPF Exiting "Dropped" Combobox, Items no longer editable?

Tags: wpf, drop-down-menu, combobox

Friends,

I have a WPF Combobox. When the Combobox is opened, I have the items dynamically generated based upon environment variables. So basically a combobox that is bound to a list that is dynamically changing.

Everything works as expected until I Exit the combobox with the dropdown **open** to enter another control(another combobox).

When I reopen the first combobox, the items appear to be frozen and no longer bound to the list when INDEED the list is changing and is still bound. Its almost like the binding broke.

When this event occurs, I have attempted to forcefully add items, and that doesn't work either. I can see in the code behind that the combobox now contains the additional items, yet it doesn't appear that contain them in the UI.

What is this black magic? Any way to prevent it? is this some type of Stuck focus issue? Maybe the dropdown isn't re-sizing?

I think i have narrowed it down to the physical dropdown is not re-sizing to the new items.

EDIT*

The controls are dynamically generating, so I have no real hard code to show you other than this.

```
private void CBControl_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((ComboBox)sender).Items.Add("Option");
}
```

On this event, I will add an items to the combobox, although the items ARE being added to the list, they are not displayed in the UI.

EDIT 2*

I figured it out, so i have 2 comboboxes, it appears that the 2nd was steeling and holding the focus INSIDE the dropdown. (odd bug)

in order to fix it i needed to release it bu changing the index of the 2nd combo box WHILE it is open.

```
int sel = ComboBoxTwo.SelectedIndex;
ComboBoxTwo.IsDropDownOpen = true;
ComboBoxTwo.SelectedIndex = -1;
ComboBoxTwo.IsDropDownOpen = true;
ComboBoxTwo.SelectedIndex = sel;
```

and I had to manage the unintended recursive call.

Comment: Could we see the code you're using? It's great that you can describe the problem to us, but seeing the XAML and any code-behind would be much more beneficial.

Comment: Thats the sad part, it is dynamically generating based upon environment variables. None of these controls are hard coded. I wish I could post some code, although it doesn't do any justice. Here is an example, on the "DropDownOpened" event, this is what Could be running, '        private void CBControl_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((ComboBox)sender).Items.Add("Option");
        }'

Comment: So, there isn't actually an ItemSource that the ComboBox is binding to? You're just adding an item to the Items collection in the code-behind? I haven't done something like that in a while, but I'm not sure that adding to the Items collection will actually force the UI to update.

Comment: nah, i did that just for the sample, it also doesn't work. I am in fact using ItemsSource on an ObservableCollection<string> (also doesn't work)

Comment: Are you properly implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the ObservableCollection?

Comment: Yep, just validated that too... its almost like the 2nd control is holding the focus and not releasing it.

Comment: Is the second control doing something that locks up the UI?

Comment: sadly no. No event takes place in that second control. its almost like the second control has stolen the focus and wont release it for the first combobox to restore focus.

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS! i think i fixed it, the 2nd control IS steeling and not releasing the focus!!!  i had to force the 2nd control UI to release focus by changing its selected index a number of times and opening and closing its dropdown.   that's a nasty bug.  Thank you Sean for the help!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Wow, that's really strange. Glad you figured it out, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here it is.

You got 2 ComboBoxes. If you Open one then directly click into another, the focus is moved to the second combobox dropdown.

If you make any changes to the first combobox, the changes will not take effect to the style(dropdown resize) UNTIL you release the focus from the 2nd combo box dropdown item. Although the items change will take effect, the resize wont.

to release the focus, you need to open the second combox and change the selected index like so:

```
    int sel = ComboBoxTwo.SelectedIndex;
    ComboBoxTwo.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    ComboBoxTwo.SelectedIndex = -1;
    ComboBoxTwo.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    ComboBoxTwo.SelectedIndex = sel;
```

10 hours of debugging. 5 hours of research. First solution I have found. It may be dirty, but its all I can find.